# conditionally filling blanks in pandas according multiple columns from other rows

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I have a huge df with missing entries in the brand column that needs to be filled according to other rows. if the all other 3 columns match, fill the blanks with the existing brand, else fill with 'Other'.
if this is my starting df:

```
df_start = pd.DataFrame({'device_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],
'head':['a','a','b','b','a','b','a','b','b','b','a','b','c','d'],
'supplement':['Salt','Salt','Pepper','Pepper','Pepper','Pepper','Salt','Pepper','Salt','Pepper','Pepper','Salt','Pepper','Salt'],
'brand':['white',np.nan,np.nan,'white','white','black',np.nan,np.nan,'white','black',np.nan,'white','black',np.nan]})
```

how to get this result:

```
df_end = pd.DataFrame({'device_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],
'head':['a','a','b','b','a','b','a','b','b','b','a','b','c','d'],
'supplement':['Salt','Salt','Pepper','Pepper','Pepper','Pepper','Salt','Pepper','Salt','Pepper','Pepper','Salt','Pepper','Salt'],
'brand':['white','white','white','white','white','black','Other','black','white','black','Other','white','black','Other']})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try with a  `groupby` on the columns that need to be the same, in your case 'device_id', 'head', 'supplement', and use forward fill `ffill()`, backward fill `bfill()`, and at the very end you `fillna()` with 'Other', as the leftovers will be the ones with no identical rows in those 3 columns:

```
result = df_start.groupby(['device_id','head','supplement'])\
        .apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill().fillna('Other'))
```

---

prints:

```
>>> result

    device_id head supplement  brand
0           1    a       Salt  white
1           1    a       Salt  white
2           1    b     Pepper  white
3           1    b     Pepper  white
4           2    a     Pepper  white
5           2    b     Pepper  black
6           3    a       Salt  Other
7           3    b     Pepper  black
8           3    b       Salt  white
9           3    b     Pepper  black
10          4    a     Pepper  Other
11          4    b       Salt  white
12          4    c     Pepper  black
13          4    d       Salt  Other
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution not requiring a group by (costly), based on a simple mapping.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# create a mapping (ddict with key ('device_id', 'head', 'supplement')
# returns 'Other' when missing key

mapping = defaultdict(lambda: 'Other')
mapping.update(df_start.dropna()\
       .set_index(['device_id', 'head', 'supplement'])['brand']\
       .to_dict())

# apply function using the mapping to get the brand
brand = df_start.iloc[:, :-1].apply(lambda row: mapping[tuple(row)], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `nan` values in the `brands` column after the creation of the dataframe. This may not be be the most efficient way but is the simplest one.

```py
df['brand'].replace(np.NaN, "Other")
```